# How can I send an image via /cart/add.js

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I created a custom product builder where you can enter your details and they are sent along with the product order. All fields have a `name="properties[]"` attribute. I have a field to upload a picture and it sends it along with the order.

Now, the task is to validate the fields before adding a product to the cart, so I threw `e.preventDefault()` on the add to cart button and then send the product by Ajax via /cart/add.js.

But the problem is that the picture is not sent this way. How can I send a photo via /cart/add.js so that it appears in the order in the admin panel?
Below is my submission code. As I understand it, when adding a photo it converts it . And changes the name. But when I send it custom, it adds the wrong image and does not send it. Is it possible to fix it?

```js
const productFormBtn = document.querySelector(
  ".content-builder__sidebar form .product-form__submit"
);

const cardForm = document.querySelector(".content-builder__sidebar form");

productFormBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const formData = new FormData(cardForm);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "/cart/add.js", true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.responseType = "json";

      xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
          console.log("Success:", xhr.response);
         }else {
            console.error("Error:", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
          }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
          console.error("Network error");
        };

        xhr.send(new URLSearchParams(formData));
      });
```

[image: normal file sending]
[image: sending via /cart/add.js]

Answer (score 0):

You can only upload images for your custom product by using Line Item Properties. You best do that at the product template level. Shopify has a few examples you can follow. Once your customer uploads an image, that line item property is available in the cart for rendering. It is also in the order.

You can see that by inspecting any Shopify theme and cart.liquid, as they all come with support for rendering line item property images.

If you try and add the image at the cart as a property, and it is messed up, that could be because of how you're dealing with the upload. I never deal with trying to edit images this way, it is usually a do it once and forget it kind of thing.

Comment: The problem is that I need to do custom validation for the fields, so I'm looking for a way to do this

Comment: What fields?  What validation? You either use Shopify the way it is, or you re-invent the wheel with 100x the code yourself an deal with the increased complexity too! I was only pointing you to the cheap, easy and free plan. Your needs up the ante 100x or more.

Comment: What are my needs? Initially, the question was whether it was possible to send the image inserted by the client via /cart/add.js

Comment: I am sure you can. My point was, it is much much much easier doing that from the product template, when the customer chooses that product, chooses their image, and then the form gets submitted to cart/add at that time. You can of course not do that, and do it from the cart, but your challenge is harder, as you're finding out.